# Alert if echo'd SQL table has been modified

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table

I have a HTML table that is echo'ing data from my SQL database. 
What I need is for an alert to pop up on the HTML page whenever a certain field in the table is updated in the database from elsewhere.

On my homepage where the table is located, it is displaying a table from my getTable.php file.

The specific column I am wanting updates for is a notes column that will regularly have input from operators in the factory.

I'm not sure what code will be helpful at all to help understand the situation, but am looking for any advice on non-javascript functions that can simply keep a tab on whether an SQL table is being edited.

Here is the code for the cell that indicates to me that there is a note present:

```
$conN = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER);
        if (!$conN) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conN));} // Check Connection
        mysqli_select_db($conN,"jms");

        $jid = $row['jobID'];
        $opn = $row['operation'];
        $highlight = mysqli_query($conN,"SELECT notes FROM operations WHERE jobID=$jid AND operation=$opn");
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($highlight))
            if (isset($data['notes']) && $data['notes'] != "") {
            echo "<td id='notes' style='background-color:red;width:1%;' onChange='alert(\"New note on Job No " .$jid. "\")'><input id='target' type='text' value='" .$data["notes"]. "' >" . "</td>";
            } else {
            echo "<td style='background-color:palegreen;width:1%;'>" . "</td>";
            }
        echo "</tr>"; // End the row
        $index++;
```

Comment: I made a cell that echoes the value of the note, and made that an input so I could manually change it. That works to pop up an alert when I change the text in it, but when it changes from the PHP query itself, it doesn't give me a notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a more complicated thing than you were expecting.

There are a few options to implement this, and they depend on what control you have over the larger system.  Ultimately, with PHP you will likely need to use a method of polling.

To use a simple example, you could use JavaScript to hit an AJAX PHP script, and POST it the current array of data.  Then, the PHP could check the current data, and compare the two arrays.  This might not be very efficient, but it'd allow you to tell when a field changes.

To make this more optimal, you could store a modification time on each row.  Then you only need to send the last highest modification time, and use an index to check for newer records.  The AJAX PHP script would then send data back only if it was newer.  You might still need an array to tell which particular field changed, but that could be done on the client side.

Another option is to use TRIGGERs (if your database engine supports them), which could update a separate table with change information.  Then you could use a cursor to send this information through AJAX polling.

Continuing down that trail, you could replace the AJAX with a websocket.  If you need the information as real time as possible, this could be more efficient.  The code it connects to ultimately will still need to be polling, though (unless it's a long-lived app that updates also go through... this is very unlikely if you're using PHP, though.)

Anyway, one way or another, the ingredients you need are:

1. JavaScript to ask the server for changes either every X amount of time or through a long-lived websocket.
2. A way to identify when the data is different (like modification time, result set, TRIGGER changelog table, etc.)
3. Something on the server to check that and report the information back.
4. JavaScript to display the changes to the user when they occur.

Comment: You're right, it's definitely more complicated than I imagined. I'm only a beginner in all kinds of script. This is roughly my second month of working with html, php and js while working somewhere as a mechanical engineer.

Comment: If you really want to avoid JavaScript, you could store the data in $_SESSION, and then have the page refresh every X amount of time (using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), and use PHP to output the alert.  Or even, if you can live without the alert, meta refresh will make it update automatically, more or less.